# Looking for an online mobile testing service

Tags: manual-testing, android, mobile

I had come across an online Mobile App testing service that offered their services for $10/hour a few days back. I am now searching all over the internet and can't recollect what their name was.

Basically, they had a huge variety of hardware devices connected on their server. A user could sign up for their service and then install their app on as many devices as they want to test them out. Billing was flat $10/hour.

I am about to go live with my first Android app and want to make sure that this app installs and functions a good amount of popular devices.

If you anyone of you have used a similar service, please let me know. I am on a tight budget for this app, so not really looking for a $500+ per month kind of a service.

Comment: Hi Moiz, I know this is an older question, but I closed it because I'm not sure it matches the kind of question we're looking for here, and it was attracting attention from newer users. I hope that isn't a problem. =]

Comment: Try with crowd source testing for mobile app testing. Crowd source testing, also known as crowd testing allows more individuals to participate, often at a reduced cost and with better testing quality. Opting for a solid software testing community will be beneficial. I have come across http://qualitrix.com/ and https://www.passbrains.com/ which allows its users to select their crowd among the community of testers and tests the app in a real world environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the service that I was looking for by searching my browser history - http://appkitbox.com/en/testkit The best part I like about them is for a relatively inexpensive $10/hour I can rent any device and test my app on it. (I am in no way related to this service that I am recommending). Hope this helps the community at large - those who are developing mobile apps.

Comment: Could you please mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need to test your app on mobile device, you can obviously go for simulators and emulators, there are plenty of free online simulators are available.
you can see this site for more information:
http://sixrevisions.com/tools/10-excellent-tools-for-testing-your-site-on-mobile-devices/